# What is the English translation of this French Canadian method of "picking" wild blueberries with a racket?

Tags: foraging

When I was younger I remember going berry picking with a net (similarly to a butterfly net) and a racket. Where you would whack the blueberry bush with the racket and catch the blueberries knocked off with the net. I'm trying to find the English name of this method. (Reason: I want to show my wife this method and I'm trying to look up the dos and don'ts and what type of "racket" I need for it)

In my research I've been able to find an image of someone doing it at [tourduquebec.ca](https://tourduquebec.ca/terroir/pelerinage-aux-bleuets-sauvages/):

[image]
[image]

I've also been able to find a mention of the act on [a historical webpage of the Québec National Library and Archives](http://rdaq.banq.qc.ca/expositions_virtuelles/coutumes_culture/juillet/cueillettes/coutume_culture.html):

> Moins fragiles que les autres petits fruits, les bleuets peuvent se cueillir à l'aide d'instruments et selon des techniques très simples. Par exemple, on les cueille «à la tape» ou «à la claque». Cette technique consiste à taper sur les plants à l'aide de la main ou d'une «tapette», nom donné à divers objets comme un couvercle ou un poêlon, de manière à faire tomber les fruits dans un contenant.

Google translate for convenience:

> Less fragile than other small fruits, blueberries can be picked using very simple tools and techniques. For example, they are picked "à la slap" or "à la slaque". This technique consists of tapping on the plants using the hand or a "swatter", a name given to various objects such as a lid or a pan, so as to drop the fruit into a container.

Comment: You might want to change the pictures in the question because the tool used is a berry comb.

Comment: Doesn't a berry comb need some sort of teeth?

Comment: Yes, you can see them in the picture, that's why I was commenting.

Comment: I can only see one thing that looks like a tooth are the black lnes bellow his white tool on the second picture, but that would only be a single tooth. The rim of the bucket on the first picture seems to be smooth (no teeth). Could you guide me as to where you see the teeth?

Comment: The white one in the foreground has black teeth on the comb.

Comment: There are several long wire teeth visible in the second picture, and they are mostly hidden in the first, but these are two pictures of the same person during the same picking session. The source article even mentions he uses a comb: "Équipé d’un gros peigne avec des dents de métal et un manche en fibre de verre [...]" which is translated to "Equipped with a large metal toothed comb with a glass fiber handle [...]".

Comment: In Bulgarian that's called "комбайн" == "reaper, combine, harvester" as per google translate. It gets used for camomile as well.

Comment: What we see in the basket – many branches and leaves – this is **poaching**. It takes years for blueberry till it begins to give berries. Harvester/picker should not tear off branches neither leaves.